# Access AD access users OneDrive through Microsoft Graph API error "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to access my sharepoint/onedrive files via the Microsoft Graph API. I have a sharepoint/onedrive account, and I have many API permissions set, including 'Files.readwrite.all' and 'Sites.readwrite.all'. I can see that this user does have files in an online onedrive, but I'm not able to query them. The queries are successfully when I use the graph explorer under the users account. I am using 'Application Permissions'. Any idea how to fix?

Here are some broad queries that work & don't work:
graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Returns a list of users without issues.

graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN-PLACEHOLDER
Returns information about the specified user without issues.

graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN-PLACEHOLDER/drive
DOES NOT WORK - Error "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL"

graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN-PLACEHOLDER/drive/root
DOES NOT WORK - Error "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL"

This is the specific code

```
SCOPE = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
CLIENT_SECRET = 
TENENT_ID = 
APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID = 
AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TENENT_ID
KFM_USER_ID =
ENDPOINT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + KFM_USER_ID # THIS DOES WORK
ENDPOINT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + KFM_USER_ID + "/drive" # THIS ISN"T WORKING :(


import msal
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=SCOPE)

graph_data = requests.get(
        ENDPOINT,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
).json()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [**MS Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#get-a-users-onedrive),

> If a user's OneDrive is **not provisioned** but the user has a license to use OneDrive, this request will automatically provision the user's drive, when using **delegated** authentication.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted API permissions as below:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment for user having **valid** license but not yet provisioned, I got **same error**:

```py
import requests
import msal

SCOPE = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
CLIENT_SECRET = "secret"
TENENT_ID = "tenantId"
APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID = "appId"
AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TENENT_ID
KFM_USER_ID = "userId"
#ENDPOINT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + KFM_USER_ID # THIS DOES WORK
ENDPOINT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + KFM_USER_ID + "/drive" # THIS ISN"T WORKING :(

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=SCOPE)

graph_data = requests.get(
        ENDPOINT,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
).json()

print(graph_data)
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, you need to use **delegated** authentication
> like authorization code flow, username password flow, interactive flow etc... by granting **`Delegated`** permissions.

In my case, I used **username password** flow to acquire token for which below option should be **enabled**(wait for few minutes after enabling as there will be delay):

[image]

Now, I granted below API permissions of **`Delegated`** type in that application:

[image]

When I ran below modified code with **username password** flow, I got **response** successfully:

```py
import requests
import msal

SCOPE = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
CLIENT_SECRET = "secret"
TENENT_ID = "tenantId"
APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID = "appId"
AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TENENT_ID
KFM_USER_ID = "demosriId"
USERNAME = "demosri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
#ENDPOINT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + KFM_USER_ID # THIS DOES WORK
ENDPOINT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + KFM_USER_ID + "/drive" 

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY)

result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(scopes=SCOPE, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)

graph_data = requests.get(
        ENDPOINT,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
).json()

print(graph_data)
```

**Response:**

[image]

> As [**Graph
> Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)
> involves user to sign in, it comes under **delegated** authentication
> that works with **`Delegated`** permissions. So, the above queries
> will work in it by automatically provisioning user's drive.

Once user's drive is provisioned, you can also run your code with **client credentials** flow again that gives you same **response** successfully like below:

```py
import requests
import msal

SCOPE = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
CLIENT_SECRET = "secret"
TENENT_ID = "tenantId"
APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID = "appId"
AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TENENT_ID
KFM_USER_ID = "userId"
#ENDPOINT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + KFM_USER_ID # THIS DOES WORK
ENDPOINT = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + KFM_USER_ID + "/drive" # THIS ISN"T WORKING :(

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=SCOPE)

graph_data = requests.get(
        ENDPOINT,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
).json()

print(graph_data)
```

**Response:**

[image]